# Как отобразить QML виджет на весь родительский блок?

Tags: c++, qt5, qml

Мне надо отобразить `QMl` на весь родительский блок. Если не задавать ширину и высоту, то `QML`, соответственно, не отобразится. Если задавать явно - будет статичным. Как сделать так, чтобы блок был "резиновым" - растягивался под нужные размеры?

```
width: 400
height: 400
```

[image: Статичный QML блок]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Достаточно сделать так:

```
map->setSource(QUrl("qrc:map.qml"));
map->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
```

Вторая строка спасительная.

Comment: а разве в `qml` этот режим нельзя поставить?

Comment: @AndrioSkur я тоже так думал... Поставил anchors.fill: parent, но не сработало. Почему - не знаю, но не сработало.

Comment: А точно не сработало? Не может быть что компонент занял весь размер родительского блока, но карту рисовал только на части? Как вариант, можно попробовать  привязать каждую из сторон отдельно ( anchors.left: parent.left;  anchors.right: parent.right и т.д.)

Comment: @aknew к сожалению нет. Никакой из вышеперечисленных не подошёл, подошёл только C++ способ.